# How to install and configure NTP Server on vSphere?

Tags: ntp

I need to install and configure NTP service on VMware vSphere
, Need help for the same.
I tried many solutions but none of them worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This can be done with following Steps:**

1. Configure NTP servers on ESXI Server (physical host).
2. Synchronize virtual machines with Server.